# I want to names dataframe's columns using a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I want to name dataframe's columns using a vector of character. I don't know why with the following code I get the error:

> Error in names(x) <- value :
> 'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [1]

```
vec <- 1:5
vec <- as.data.frame(vec)
colnames(vec) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as.data.frame` still returns a single column.  Instead, we may need to use `as.data.frame.list`

```
vec <- 1:5
vec <- as.data.frame.list(vec)
colnames(vec) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

-output

```
> vec
  a b c d e
1 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
vec <- 1:5
vec <- as.data.frame(t(vec))
colnames(vec) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

Output:

```
    a b c d e
  1 1 2 3 4 5
```